# MVVM pattern for Windows 8 - project template?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, mvvm, windows-store-apps

Is there any Visual Studio template for Windows 8 applications that use MVVM out of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio go to Create New Project and search for w8mvvm or just mvvm.

Template: [MVVM for Windows 8](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b287f569-7bf9-40d2-80f3-02c9945f1f33)

Docs: [http://w8mvvm.codeplex.com/](http://w8mvvm.codeplex.com/documentation)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MVVM Light` `Windows 8`

Lien : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj651572.aspx

Download : http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/

Comment: +1 because MVVM Light is definitely light and useful.

Comment: Thank's ken2k i like this template easy and very good